# Fedora installation .bin file

Tags: fedora

I'm a Fedora (well linux actually!) novice and I am trying to install some software but am having problems.

It is a .tar.gz file and I've extracted it using `tar -zxvf`, and that has given me a .bin file. This is where i am stuck, as I can't find anywhere that says how to install a .bin file on Fedora. It's in a directory that I've given full permissions to my user to exectue files from.

Does anyone know if it is possible to install a .bin file, or has ever done it and could give me some pointers?

Answer (score 2):

A file extension alone tells nothing in the Linux world. But I would guess it's some kind of an executable file. Have you tried running it by first giving it execute permissions with `chmod +x file.bin`, and then doing `./file.bin` on the directory the file resides?

You should see if the package can be found from the system's own software repositories first, though. It'll help you manage what all you have installed, and provides version updates in a centralized way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply jho. I htink that permissions may be something to do with this, but I can't seem to change the permissions for the .bin file. I changed them for the .tar.gz earlier to execute and that worked but when I try to change it for this file so I can run it it says: "chmod: changing permissions of 'file.bin': read-only file system

Comment: @5lovak: Woah, is the .bin in the same directory you successfully changed permissions in for the .tar.gz? It's definitely not a good sign if a file system suddely goes into read-only mode, that can indicate severe problems with your hard drive or file system, not the file alone. What's the output of `mount`, and where is the .bin file located? Also if everything else is working fine, you should try moving the .bin elsewhere, like your home directory or `/tmp` and see if you can change its permissions there.

Comment: I think that the VM might be screwed. I have tried some more but had to leave this for the time being until I get a chance to re-install. Thanks very much for your advice though jho.